# Regex parsing multiple elements, with the first one being optional

Tags: regex

I am trying to integrate my timesheets app with Fogbugz by using a text pattern in the time entry's notes to indicate that work was done on a case.

Scenario A:
If work was done on case#123, the note would be:
[123] Rewrote javascript code.

Desired output: Case: 123 Note: Rewrote javascript code.

Scenario B:
If work was not related to a case, the note would be:
Rewrote javascript code.

Desired output: Case: Null Note: Rewrote javascript code.

---

To parse the string, I'm using Pentaho Data Integration's Regex Evaluation transformation, but I think the regex would probably be the same regardless of the tool in question.

This is the code that I'm using:

```
(\[(.*)\])(.*)
```

For Scenario A, I get:
Ignorable field: [123]
Case: 123
Note: Rewrote javascript code.

Scenario B, I get:
Ignorable field: null
Case: Null
Note: Null

Now to the question (finally!) - is there a way for me to get the note portion to show up if there is no "[##]" pattern showing up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to try this:

```
(\[(.*)\])?\s*(.*)
```

Comment: That worked! Thanks! Regex has always felt a little like rocket science to me.

Answer (score 1):

```
^\s*(\[[^]]+\])?\s*(.*)
```

Don't use `.*` if you don't absolutely, positively want to match *everything*. What you are trying to match is "everything up to the closing `]`", and this should be explicit in the regex.

Explanation:

```
^          # start-of-string
\s*        # any number of leading white-space (gets ignored)
(          # match group 1
  \[       # literal [
  [^]]+    # anything but ]
  \]       # literal ]
)?         # end match group 1, make optional
\s*        # any number of intermediary white-space (gets ignored, too)
(.*)       # anything else on that line
```

Answer (score 0):

That's not strictly a regex problem.  It consists of two parts:  regex matching, and then apply a little logic:
if the [n+] part matched, output "\1 Note" else "Null Note".