# Parsing a regex for optional sections

Tags: python, regex

Similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1876217/regex-parsing-multiple-elements-with-the-first-one-being-optional) but with a difference subtle enough that I still need some help.

Currently I have:

```
'(.*)\[(\d+\-\d+)\]'
```

as my regex, which matches any number of characters followed by square brackets [] that contain two decimals separated by a dash. My issue is, I'd like it to also match with just one decimal number between the square brackets, and possibly even with nothing in between the square brackets. So:

```
word[1-5] = match
word[5] = match
word[] = match (not essential)
```

and ensuring

```
word[-5] = no match
```

Could anyone possibly point my in the direction of the next step. I currently find regex to be a bit of a guessing game though I would like to become better with them.

Comment: You do realize that if your target string has more than one `[dd-dd]` structure per line, then your expression matches _only the last one_ - the `(.*)` happily marches past all of them to the end of the line and the engine then must backtrack to find the last `[dd-dd]`. Beware the dot-star!

Comment: I do :) in this case the [dd-dd] format at the end of the line will be stripped off and used for determining a range, and anything preceeding it, i.e. the (.*) group, will just be considered to be the "name"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go with yours and make the last part optional

```
(.*)\[(\d+(-\d+)?)\]
```

Using `?`.

To accomplish the other task, well, go with `?` again

```
(.*)\[(\d+(-\d+)?)?\]
                  ^here
```

A working example http://rubular.com/r/t0MaHyHfeS

Answer (score 1):

Use `?` to match 0 or 1 match

So use `?` for the `-\d+` and for both the digits separated by `-`

```
(.*)\[(\d+(-\d+)?)?\]
```

No need to escape `-`..It has special meaning only if its's between a character class.

Answer (score 0):

`(.*)\[((\d+(?:\-\d+)?)?)\]`

This will match everything, even with 0 digits in there and will backreference you (in match[1-5]):

1- match
2- 1-5

Answer (score 0):

Not every regex interpreter supports this, but you could try an "or" operator for the part inside the brackets:

```
'(.*)\[(\d+\-\d+|\d+)\]'
```